# SwiftUI: State variable from observed singleton property leads to error

Tags: swiftui, singleton, observableobject, observedobject

I use a singleton to access subscription offerings from RevenueCat as an `@ObservedObject` on various views in the app:

```
import Foundation
import Purchases
import SwiftUI

class SubscriptionManager: ObservableObject {
    static let shared = SubscriptionManager()

    @Published var offerings: Purchases.Offerings? = nil
    
    public func loadOfferings() {
        Purchases.shared.offerings { (offerings, error) in
            self.offerings = offerings
        }
    }
}
```

and then in the view

```
struct MyView: View {
    @ObservedObject var subManager = SubscriptionManager.shared

    // Currently selected package. Select initially the first one
    // A) like this the var doesn't update when the ObservedObject updates the offerings var
    @State private var selectedPackage: Purchases.Package? = SubscriptionManager.shared.offerings?.current?.availablePackages.first

    // B) like this it gives the error "Cannot use instance member 'subManager' within property initializer; property initializers run before 'self' is available"
    @State private var selectedPackage: Purchases.Package? = subManager.offerings?.current?.availablePackages.first

    var body: some View {
        // Paywall UI which displays the packages once the singleton loaded them and. which changes var selectedPackage if user selects a package
        // ...
    }
}
```

How can I properly define a `@State` var depending on the `@ObservedObject` published property which doesn't give me the error A or B

Comment: Your `subManager` is already observed, why do you need states? Use observed directly.

Comment: @Asperi The purpose of the var selectedPackage is to keep track of the user's selected package. If the user taps a package, the var is updated and all the related UI will update accordingly. subManager doesn't keep track of the user's selected package, that's only relevant for MyView and related child views

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A possible variant is to observe changes in manager at set state correspondingly, like

```
struct MyView: View {
    @ObservedObject var subManager = SubscriptionManager.shared

    @State private var selectedPackage: Purchases.Package?

    // ... 

    var body: some View {
      
       SomeViewHere()
          .onChange(of: subManager.offerings) {
             self.selectedPackage = $0?.current?.availablePackages.first  // << here !!
          }

    }
}
```

also you should update published property on main queue (or make `SubscriptionManager` main actor, if min spec allows), like

```
public func loadOfferings() {
    Purchases.shared.offerings { (offerings, error) in
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
           self.offerings = offerings
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks that works. Important to mention, .onChange works only for iOS 14+.